# How to optimized mysql query having large dataset

Tags: mysql, performance, index-tuning, query-performance

I have two tables in MySql with the following schema,

```
CREATE TABLE `open_log` (
  `delivery_id` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_activity` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `click_url` text,
  `email_code` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `on_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `sent_log` (
  `email_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `delivery_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_code` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `delivery_status` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tries` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creation_ts` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creation_dt` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `on_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The email_id and delivery_id columns in both tables make up a unique key.

The open_log table have 2.5 million records where as sent_log table has 0.25 million records.

I want to filter out the records from open log table based on the unique key (email_id and delivery_id).

I'm writing the following query.

SELECT * FROM open_log
WHERE CONCAT(email_id,'^',delivery_id) 
IN (
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(email_id,'^',delivery_id) FROM sent_log
)

The problem is the query is taking too much time to execute. I've waited for an hour for the query completion but didn't succeed.

I've tried to make the email_id and delivery_id as composite key but that didn't help.

Kindly, suggest what I can do to make it fast since, I have the big data size in the tables.

Thanks,
Faisal Nasir

Answer (score 1):

- First, if `email_id` and `delivery_id` together are a unique key, please add a primary -composite- key on both tables for `(email_id, delivery_id)`
- Second, the concat is not necessary and will prevent the previous key from being used. Try:

  ```
  SELECT ol.* 
  FROM open_log ol 
  JOIN sent_log sl 
  ON (ol.email_id, ol.delivery_id) = (sl.email_id, sl.delivery_id)
  ```

Comment: I like this syntax but the `ON ol.email_id = sl.email_id AND ol.delivery_id = sl.delivery_id` results in more optimal code than `ON (ol.email_id, ol.delivery_id) = (sl.email_id, sl.delivery_id)` in some versions.

Comment: @ypercube, not true, MySQL has *a bug* for certain uses of that syntax (I think it was fixed in 5.7?), let's speak clearly. Not in OPs use.

Comment: What if the OP uses 5.1 or 5.0? Anyway, I'm not really sure, have to check it out. It may not affect `=` but only `>=` and `IN` comparisons.

Comment: @ypercube it will work http://pastebin.com/XwgiW7j4

Comment: @ypercube, exactly the bug I mention is the `(a, b) IN ((c, d), (e, f))`, where indexes are not used- but return correct results.

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't remember in what circumstances  the indexes were not used.